# Parse nested json array in android using volley?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have the sample Json format here and I would like to parse using android volley but i got stuck with the error:
at entry of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

```
    {
  "entry": {
    "": {
      "": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/Atom",
      "m": "http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/ado\/2007\/08\/dataservices\/metadata",
      "d": "http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/ado\/2007\/08\/dataservices"
    },
    "FOO_BLOCK": {
      "BAR_xmlbase": "https:\/\/ab.com:443\/dap\/opu\/odata\/dap\/BATCH_SRV\/"
    },
    "id": {
      "TEXT": "https:\/\/ab.com:443\/dap\/opu\/odata\/dap\/BATCH_SRV\/BatchSet('1000')"
    },
    "title": {
      "FOO_BLOCK": {
        "BAR_type": "text"
      },
      "TEXT": "BatchSet('1000')"
    },
    "updated": {
      "TEXT": "2018-06-05T13:45:24Z"
    },
    "category": {
      "FOO_BLOCK": {
        "BAR_term": "BATCH_SRV.Batch",
        "BAR_scheme": "http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/ado\/2007\/08\/dataservices\/scheme"
      },
      "TEXT": "NULL"
    },
    "link": {
      "FOO_BLOCK": {
        "BAR_href": "BatchSet('1000')",
        "BAR_rel": "self",
        "BAR_title": "Batch"
      },
      "TEXT": "NULL"
    },
    "content": {
      "FOO_BLOCK": {
        "BAR_type": "application\/xml"
      },
      "mproperties": {
        "dCharg": {
          "TEXT": 1000
        },
        "dICharg": {
          "TEXT": 1000
        },
        "dMaktx": {
          "TEXT": "No Material description avaibalbe"
        },
        "dStatus": {
          "TEXT": "Batch is unrestricted"
        },
        "dStock": {
          "TEXT": "NULL"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the code which i have write in android.

```
JsonObjectRequest arrReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject >() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {
                        Log.e("FD", response.toString());
                        // Check the length of our response (to see if the user has any repos)
                        // Process the JSON
                        try{
                            // Get the JSON array
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("entry");
                            Log.e("FD", jsonArray.toString());


                            // Loop through the array elements
                            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                                // Get current json object
                                JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);


                                String Charg = student.getString("Charg");
                                String Status = student.getString("Status");

                                // Display the formatted json data in text view

                                addToRepoList(Charg , Status );
                            }

                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // If there a HTTP error then add a note to our repo list.
                        setRepoListText("Error while calling REST API");
                        Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
```

But i am getting Errors while parsing it in Android. The error is- JSONObject can not be converted to JSONArray

Can anyone please provide sample code to parse this json Array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Your `entry` is not a `JSONOArray` but yes a `JSONObject`. In your json response nothing are a `JSONArray`

Try something like this:

```
JSONObject entryObj = response.getJSONObject("entry")
```

And then:

```
JSONObject fooBlockObj = entryObj.getJSONObject("FOO_BLOCK")
...
JSONObject contentObj = entryObj.getJSONObject("content")
JSONObject mProperties = contentObj.getJSONObject("mproperties")
JSONObject dCharg = mProperties.getJSONObject("dCharg")
JSONObject dStatus = mProperties.getJSONObject("dStatus")
```

Finally

```
String charg = dCharg.getString("TEXT")
String status = dStatus.getString("TEXT")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `json response` does not contain a `json array`. Some of the issues that should be noted are

- `entry` is a json object but you are parsing it as an array
- you are trying to fetch the keys `Charg, Status` from the json which are not even present in the response (instead `dCharg, dStatus` are present, which might be the keys you want)

If you need to fetch the keys `Charg, Status`, check the following

```
                 try{
                     JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("entry");
                     JSONObject content = data.getJSONObject("content");
                     JSONObject mproperties = content.getJSONObject("mproperties");
                     JSONObject status = mProperties.getJSONObject("dStatus")
                     JSONObject charg = mProperties.getJSONObject("dCharg")
                     String statusText = status.getString("TEXT")
                     String chargText = charg.getString("TEXT")
                    }

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```